# How can I trigger form submit with HTML validation from child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, form-submit, onsubmit

I have a component with thie structure

```js
handleSubmit(event) {

        ... handle submission

    }
```

```js
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <Sidebar
            handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
            handler={this.loadTemplateCV}
        ></Sidebar>
</form>
```

only inside the sidebar component I have the submit button like so:

```js
function Sidebar(props) {

    ...

    return (
        <div className="flex-shrink-0 w-80 bg-gray-200 border-gray-300 border
             <button className="button-format" type="submit" onClick={props.handleSubmit()}>
                 Submit
             </button>
         </div>)
}
```

How can I trigger a submit with HTML form validation from the children component? When I try like this, the handleEvent triggers as `undefined`. I can manually still handle submission data without the event but that doesn't trigger HTML form validation which I want.

Comment: Remove the parentheses of `props.handleSubmit` and try again

Comment: @legenddaniel that does nothing apparently